# How to add multiple columns in flask sqlachemy and return it as a single column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

am trying to create a data base model with columns that are drived columns of other columns so the in this case its a pay roll system where by the total_benfits is a columns that is a result of adding other colums with the total benefits

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from datetime import datetime
from app import db

class Payroll(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(500),unique=False, nullable=False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(500),unique=False, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(500),unique=True, nullable=False)
    id_number = db.Column(db.String(500),unique=True, nullable=False)
    bank_details = db.Column(db.String(500),unique=True, nullable=False)
    retainer = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=False)
    discretionary_allowance = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    weekly_incentives = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True) 
    overtime = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True) 
    coupons_value = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    performance_incentives = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    anniversary_payout = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    shift_allowance = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    back_pay = db.Column(db.Fl`your text`oat, unique=False, nullable=True)
    agent_benefits = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    total_earnings = db.column_property(retainer + discretionary_allowance + weekly_incentives + overtime + coupons_value + performance_incentives + anniversary_payout + shift_allowance +back_pay + agent_benefits, db.Float)
    medical_aid = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    nssa = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    canteen = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    cicm = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    zol = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    withholding_tax = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    medical_loan = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    staff_Loan = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    independent_contractors_deduction = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    fixed_deductions = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    fixed_deductions_months = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False, nullable=True)
    total_fixed_deductions = db.column_property(fixed_deductions * fixed_deductions_months, db.Float)
    total_deductions = db.column_property(medical_aid + nssa + canteen + cicm + zol + withholding_tax + medical_loan + staff_Loan + independent_contractors_deduction + total_fixed_deductions, db.Float)
    net_Pay = db.column_property(total_earnings - total_deductions, db.Float)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Net Salary for ('{self.firstname}','{self.lastname}','is','{self.net_Pay}')"
```

but am recivibg the following error :

```
net_Pay = db.column_property(total_earnings - total_deductions, db.Float)
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'ColumnProperty' and 'ColumnProperty'
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `column_property()` method, your model class in which the attribute is located must be compatible with the `SELECT` expression. Instead, you can use the `hybrid_property()` method in `SQLAlchemy`. You can find details [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-a-hybrid).

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from datetime import datetime
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class Payroll(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(500),unique=False, nullable=False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(500),unique=False, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(500),unique=True, nullable=False)
    id_number = db.Column(db.String(500),unique=True, nullable=False)
    bank_details = db.Column(db.String(500),unique=True, nullable=False)
    retainer = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=False)
    discretionary_allowance = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    weekly_incentives = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True) 
    overtime = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True) 
    coupons_value = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    performance_incentives = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    anniversary_payout = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    shift_allowance = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    back_pay = db.Column(db.Fl`your text`oat, unique=False, nullable=True)
    agent_benefits = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    medical_aid = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    nssa = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    canteen = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    cicm = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    zol = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    withholding_tax = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    medical_loan = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    staff_Loan = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    independent_contractors_deduction = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    fixed_deductions = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=True)
    fixed_deductions_months = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False, nullable=True)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Net Salary for ('{self.firstname}','{self.lastname}','is','{self.net_Pay}')"

    @hybrid_property
    def total_earnings(self):
        return self.retainer + self.discretionary_allowance + self.weekly_incentives + self.overtime + self.coupons_value + self.performance_incentives + self.anniversary_payout + self.shift_allowance + self.back_pay + self.agent_benefits

    @hybrid_property
    def total_fixed_deductions(self):
        return self.fixed_deductions * self.fixed_deductions_months

    @hybrid_property
    def total_deductions(self): 
        return self.medical_aid + self.nssa + self.canteen + self.cicm + self.zol + self.withholding_tax + self.medical_loan + self.staff_Loan + self.independent_contractors_deduction + self.total_fixed_deductions

    @hybrid_property
    def net_Pay(self): 
        return self.total_earnings - self.total_deductions
```

Thus, the calculations you want for a `Payroll` instance are performed in Python.

For a `Payroll` instance, you can access the `total_earnings` attribute by:

```
payroll.total_earnings
```

Comment: now adding to the hybrid calculation part how do I implement a calculation in the database model that does the following Under Deductions, there should be provision for 2 columns; the first one will
be for Fixed Deductions (deductions which are applicable monthly & in
perpetuity) and the second for Variable Deductions (deductions over a
specified number of months, such that if User inputs X amount and in the
next column inputs X5, it means the amount is deducted over 5 months.
Once 5 months elapses the system STOPS deducting the amount for an
individual.)